# What is bool in C++?

Tags: c++, boolean

I ran across some very interesting code that makes me wonder about what bool is. I've always considered it to be a primitive type, like int or char or long. But today, I saw something that looked like this:

```
void boolPtrTest()
{
    bool thisBool = true;

    boolPtrHere(thisBool);

    printf("thisBool is %s\n", thisBool ? "true" : "false");
}

void boolPtrHere(bool& theBool)
{
    theBool = false; // uhh, dereferencing anyone?
}
```

And this code runs - no errors - and prints "thisBool is false"!

To further make this odd, I ran the following code:

```
bool myBool = new bool();
```

...and the code ran fine!

#### Before you go and downvote me for asking a "noobish" question

Here's my question: what **is** bool? Is it defined on an implementation-by-implementation basis? From the evidence shown above, I would say that it's a class. From a practical standpoint (disregarding the above), it would also seem proper to define a bool as a typedef to an int / char or have it #define'd. But how does one know what it is, (which would affect how you would treat it)?

EDIT: I thought I'd add that I'm working in VS 2008.

Comment: Are you simply failing to understand the concept of a C++ reference?

Comment: The code ran fine? It leaked memory.

Comment: This isn't Java, btw.  `bool myBool = new bool();` is not doing what you suspect (yielding a memory leak and the parentheses are unnecessary).

Comment: There's nothing special here. `bool` works the same as any other type such as `int` or `char`.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang:  In fact, it will compile due to the implicit pointer-to-bool conversion.  @casablanca:  At least in the case of the last example, `bool` does not work the same way as any other integral type:  a pointer cannot be implicitly converted to an integer.  A `bool` is "special" in that respect.

Comment: How's this for some silly-but-fun behavior:
bool myBool = new bool(false); // myBool now equals 'true'

Comment: @JamesM - I realized that as soon as I saw your post and changed my comment appropriately.

Comment: @adan_0: why *shouldn't* it run? what do you mean by the "uhh, dereferencing anyone" comment? It seems like you've misunderstood how C++ references work, but it's hard to be sure. can you describe to us what you *expected* from your code?

Comment: And this is why you **never** try to learn a language with knowledge from another. They are two different languages, don't mix them! You'll just screw yourself up. The only way to learn a language is from the ground up, so grab a book and go from there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @dash-tom-bang:  I see.  The modified comment is still somewhat misleading:  the parentheses after the type [definitely make a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402) concerning initialization of the variable (not in this case, obviously, because of the pointer-to-bool conversion, but in most practical cases they do).

Comment: @James - I've always thought that `new Foo` called the default ctor, as does `new Foo()`.  If that's not the case then I've been a newbie for far longer than I thought.  ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
void boolPtrHere(bool& theBool)
{
    theBool = false; // uhh, dereferencing anyone?
}
```

There is nothing wrong with this code. The bool is taken *by reference*. No dereferencing is required.

```
bool myBool = new bool();
```

`new` returns an address, which is converted to `true`, since it never returns a nonzero value. This is a common conversion, especially in C code:

```
int* my_int = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
if (!my_int) // my_int is converted to bool
    memory_error();
```

Comment: Well, never except in cases of memory exhaustion where `nothrow` semantics are specified. But yeah, I suppose that's pedantry. :)

Comment: That expression, as written, will never result in `myBool` being false. Other expressions obviously can, but there's not much to be gained from enumerating them.

Comment: @Dennis: it might in a dysfunctional environment where exceptions are disabled and all `new` expressions have an implicit `nothrow`. I've worked on more than one codebase where this is the case.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: And where would we be without pedantry? +1

Comment: @Mike: But then it's non-standard. Anyone can try to throw in corner cases, but then you're no longer working in standard C++. In standard C++ `new bool` **never ever throws**.

Comment: @GMan: non-standard indeed, but some of us still have to deal with it. I just felt like venting; apologies if I offended any C++ purists.

Comment: @Mike: That's okay. I just re-read my comment and realized I wrote `new bool` never throws...I mean never returns 0! :s

Answer (score 21):

I just don't see the "weirdness" you describe.

You declare a `bool`, initialized to `true`.
By calling a function and passing it by reference, you change its value to `false`.

Then you print out the value, and it works.
What is the problem?  More precisely, what is the evidence that something strange is happening?

Since you want to know the details, `bool` is probably either a byte(`char`) or an `int`.
When you assign it true/false, it gets the values 0 or 1. (use `sizeof` and `printf("%d")` to examine it).

I suspect the real issue is that you don't understand the **pass-by-reference** of `boolPtrHere`.  You are *not* passing a pointer to the bool.  You are passing the actual value by memory reference. (think of it as a pointer that you do not need to de-reference).

Comment: But! But! But!  The function is called bool PTR Here and they just pass it a bool!

Comment: Your function name is wrong, that's all.  It doesn't prove that bool is some sort of magic, in fact it is a primitive type.

Answer (score 9):

`bool` is a fundamental type; `true` and `false` are the only two values that an object of type `bool` that has been initialized can have.

Your function `boolPtrHere()` does not take a pointer to a `bool` (which would be a `bool*`); it takes a *reference* to a `bool`.  It works like any other reference in C++.

As for your last example:

```
bool myBool = new bool();
```

In C++, a pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool`.  The new expression returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated `bool` object.  This pointer is then converted to a `bool` and is stored in myBool.  If the pointer is null, then myBool will be false; otherwise it will be true (since `new` never returns null, `myBool` will always be true in this case).

Answer (score 4):

Bool is a well-defined primitive integral type, just like int, char, etc.  It also has mathematical conversions to other integral types, which can sometimes be confusing for people, but I don't think that is the source of your current confusion.

I'm not sure what you find remarkable about the first code segment you included.  Bools can be references, just like anything else.  It seems maybe you're confused about the difference between a pointer and a reference there.

As for the second code snippet, that is a little tricky.  that is actually a memory leak, and if we write it a different way, it should become more clear what it is doing:

```
 bool myBool = (new bool) != 0 ? true : false;
```

from that, you can see what this is doing is allocating a bool from the heap, then comparing the result to NULL/0, and using the result of that comparison for assignment to the boolean.  Note that the value originally allocated from the heap is leaked.  I'm a little surprised this doesn't generate a compiler error for you, I would suspect on some compilers it would.

Answer (score 1):

References don't need to be dereferenced. Pointers do.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

```
typedef enum { false=0, true=1 } bool;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've always considered it to be a
>   primitive type, like int or char or
>   long.

It seems that you are looking at C++ from Java perspective. In Java, primitive types are always passed by value and others are always references.

C++ is different. Any type can be a reference if declared that way. You can also declare `int &x` or `int *x`, so there is nothing weird about bool.

Answer (score 0):

One very small surprise about bool is `sizeof(bool) >= 1`.  A bool requires a full byte of storage.  This is so that they can have a unique address and be pointed to, as in the `boolPtrHere` function.

Comment: `sizeof(bool)` is at least 1, for the reason you stated, but can be larger.

Comment: It's size is implementation-defined, and not necessarily 1.