# What is bool in C/C++? A keyword or a macro?

Tags: c++, c, boolean, keyword

I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269478/what-is-bool-in-c), in which some of the answers suggest that `bool` is an integral type (IDEs also treat it as a keyword).

However, none of the answers suggest the information provided in [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdbool/), which says that `bool` is a macro which is added through `<cstdbool>` (In that case, the compilers might be implicitly adding this header while compiling to allow `bool`).  Here is the g++ version of [`<stdbool.h>`](http://ideone.com/od5blR).

So what exactly the `bool` is? A an integral type keyword or a macro?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit nothing wrong with wanting to know the answer in both languages

Comment: @OleksiyDobrodum: I would suggest asking two questions, in that case.

Comment: @Lightness, Asking 2 questions with the same content but "C" and "C++" strings, sounds silly and it doesn't add any value. Why are you being pedantic?

Comment: @iammilind: It's not pedantry; these are two separate languages with separate rules (as the answers explain), and we do not lump multiple questions on different topics into the same post on SO! Or shall we also ask how booleans work in PHP, JavaScript, Perl...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### In C, `bool` is a macro.

There is no built-in type or keyword by the name of `bool` in C, so typical implementations use the standard library to `#define` `true` and `false` to `1` and `0` respectively. Rules such as those for the `if` statement are defined in terms of "zero" and "non-zero" expressions, and therefore rely on the expanded macro definitions of `true` and `false`:

> `[C99: 6.8.4.1/2]:` In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0. In the else form, the second substatement is executed if the expression compares equal to 0. If the first substatement is reached via a label, the second substatement is not executed.

For convenience, C99 added the built-in intermediate type `_Bool`, and implementations of this language typically `#define` `bool` to `_Bool`. This type is defined thus:

> `[C99: 6.2.5/2]:` An object declared as type `_Bool` is large enough to store the values 0 and 1.

This allows for greater compatibility with C++ programs, which may include declarations of functions using the `bool` type; really, though, `#define _Bool int` would probably have sufficed.

---

#### In C++, `bool` is both a built-in type and a keyword.

The link you provided doesn't say that `bool` is a macro in C++. It says:

> The purpose in C of this header is to add a bool type and the true and false values as macro definitions.
>
> In C++, which supports those directly, the header simply contains a macro that can be used to check if the type is supported.

And this is correct.

**Semantically** (that is, in terms of "meaning" of your code), `[C++11: 3.9.1/2]` defines `bool` as an integral type in C++.

**Lexically** (that is, in terms of "appearance" in your code), `[C++11: 2.12/1]` lists it as a keyword. In fact, *all* tokens that are part of the names of integral types are also keywords, including (but not limited to):

- `int`
- `unsigned`
- `long`
- `bool`
- `short`
- `signed`

It is, however, *never* a macro in C++. Instead, you get a macro `__bool_true_false_are_defined` which you could use in multi-language code to switch treatment of `bool` depending on whether you're working in C or C++; I'm not sure I can think of a useful example, mind you.

Comment: Even I don't say in my question that "bool is a macro in C++" :-). I wanted to know how is it treated. Good that you have provided standard reference.

Comment: In C++, bool is a macro defined to bool (the keyword). false is defined to false and true is defined to true. Who cares ? Me because my IDE colors bool as a macro instead of a keyword because of that... (and that's ugly) The only way I can access the real types is by using #undef

Comment: @Winter: That is not true; some code/library/header/implementation is doing that. A program that does `#define bool bool` or `#define true true` or `#define false false` actually has undefined behaviour (though I can roughly imagine a crappy stdlib implementation doing it) so it's certainly not something about "in C++"

Comment: @BoundaryImposition It is done in stdbool.h and it's indicated "Supporting <stdbool.h> in C++ is a GCC extension". I don't have anything weird with my setup, using gcc 4.9.2 on debian.

Comment: @Winter: Right, so, a C header included only as an extension by your stdlib implementation. Nothing to do with C++. Simply don't use the header and you'll be fine.

Comment: Good to know that atomic_base.h includes it which is included by atomic.

Answer (score 8):

In C `bool` is a macro from `stdbool.h` that expands to `_Bool` which is the C boolean type.

Comment: Only since C99. Prior to that, there was no boolean type in C whatsoever. Further, `_Bool` is _numeric_, which may not be what one expects coming from C++. Really, `_Bool` is not a "boolean type"; it is simply a numeric type large enough to store both `1` and `0`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I respect the C terminology which calls `_Bool` the *boolean type* in the C Standard.

Comment: 6.1.3.2 is headed "Boolean type", but only talks about conversions: `When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.` It's a sort of faux-boolean type, by any conventional logic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it is the reason why it is called the boolean type. It is an integer type but conversions do not behave as other integer types. For example,  `(bool) 0.5` is `1`, but `(char) 0.5` or `(int) 0.5` are `0`. The term *boolean type* is also referred in *7.18 Boolean type and values <stdbool.h>* in the Standard.

Answer (score 4):

> So what exactly the bool is? A an integral type keyword or a macro?

In C++, it's called **Boolean literal**, it's build in type.

§2.14.7

Types **bool**, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called **integral types**.

§2.14.6

Boolean literals

```
boolean-literal:
false
true
```

The Boolean literals are the keywords ***false*** and ***true***. Such literals are prvalues and have type bool.

§ 3.9.1.6

> Values of type bool are either true or false. [ Note: There are no signed, unsigned, short, or long
>   bool types or values. — end note ] Values of type bool participate in integral promotions (4.5).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `bool` is a built-in data type.  In C it is not, so if you're using `bool` in C it has been implemented as a typedef or with `#define`, and `true` and `false` must have been implemented with `#define` or perhaps are constants.

Answer (score 1):

In C there is no concept like Boolean variables, Yes Higher level languages like Java, C# and other provides us the facility to declare a Boolean variable, that we use for flagging purposes to set it either true or false.

But you can implement this using integrals like we did in C

```
if(1)
{
   // Because C treats 1 and any other integer as true
}
if(0)
{
   // This time our if condition will result in false
}
```

Comment: In C, there is a type `_Bool`, and the literal constants `true` and `false` are defined in a header.  And while in C, comparison operators formally result in an `int`, the language is designed so that you can program in it as if it has a true boolean type; this has been more or less recommended practice for at least 30 years.

Comment: It really amazed me, Thanks James, I never knew it.

Comment: If anyone else has doubts on boolean variables in C please visit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c This only means you can't directly make a bool variable, you need to define it using typedef keyword , Thus answer is Both because we can define it using #define true and in other language, it is also a keyword.

Comment: Did you read the answer.  If you include `<stdbool.h>`, you can use `bool`, `true` and `false` exactly as you would in C++.  Formally, they're different, but when used normally, the differences have no impact on your code.

Comment: Yes I did, Thanks James

Answer (score 1):

In C `_Bool` is a type and `bool`, `true` and `false` are macros defined in `stdbool.h`

ISO C11 standard states (in section **6.2.5 Types** )

> An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values 0 and 1.

`stdbool.h` defines 4 macros.

1. `bool` which expands to `_Bool`
2. `true` which expands to `1`
3. `false` which expands to `0`
4. `__bool_true_false_are_defined` which expands to `1`.