# Why "bool c = nullptr ;" compiles (C++11)?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, null-pointer

I don't understand why following code [compiles](http://ideone.com/hkEpqD) ?

```
int main()
{
     //int a = nullptr;  // Doesn't Compile
     //char b = nullptr; // Doesn't Compile
       bool c = nullptr; // Compiles

       return 0;
}
```

whereas the commented section doesn't.

---

I've already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1282295/1870232) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18042253/1870232).

Both `bool` and `nullptr` are keywords, so what's unique about the other data types?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#654

Comment: *"Both bool and nullptr are keywords, so what's unique about the other data types?"* I would be glad if you clarified why the fact that they are both keywords would make a difference. If you said `std::nullptr_t p; int a = p; bool c = p;` would that make any difference for you?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Sorry for confusion, but my concern was  why `nullptr` doesn't convert to basic data type i.e `char`, `int` ?

Comment: The question and the answers are applicable to C++11, but out-of-date for any later version of the language specification. Since C++14 this impicit conversion in **NOT** allowed outside of direct-initialization contexts anymore. The above initialization does **NOT** compile.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For the same reason as

```
if( p ) { ... }
```

compiles: any value of basic type converts implicitly to boolean, with `0` converting to `false` and any other value to `true`.

Originally basic type values had to convert to `bool` for C compatibility. C didn't originally have a `bool` type, but any numerical expression could be used as a boolean (with the 0 == `false` convention). And now we're caught in the backward compatibility tangle. `nullptr` has to support idiomatic constructs such as `if(p)`, especially for the cases where old code's literal `0` or `NULL` is replaced with `nullptr`. E.g. code like `if(p)` can result from a macro expansion, or in template code.

---

**Addendum**: the technical *how* of why `nullptr` doesn't convert to e.g. `int`.

Since `nullptr` converts implicitly to `bool`, and `bool` (unfortunately) converts implicitly to `int`, one could expect that `nullptr` should also convert to `int`. But the point of `nullptr` is that it should behave as a *pointer value*. And while pointers do convert implicitly to `bool`, they do not convert implicitly to numerical types.

Arranging such a restriction for a user-defined type is however not entirely straightforward. An `operator bool` conversion will be invoked for conversion to `int`, if it's present. One C++11 solution to enfore the restriction, is to make the conversion operator a template, restricted by a `std::enable_if`, as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>  // std::enable_if, std::is_same

struct S
{
    template< class Type >
    operator Type* () const { return 0; }

    template<
        class Bool_type,
        class Enabled = typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<Bool_type, bool>::value, void
            >::type
        >
    operator Bool_type () const { return false; }
};

auto main() -> int
{
    bool const              b   = S();      // OK.
    double const*  const    p   = S();      // OK.
    int const               i   = S();      // !Doesn't compile.
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this provides the reason. `p` is not a null pointer constant. Why do you want to write literally `if(nullptr) { ... }`?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: your comment is apparently **meaningless**. would you care to expand on (1) why you think I would want write literally `if(nullptr){...}`, and (2) what the heck that has to do with anything? for that matter, also the baffling (3) "p is not a null pointer constant", where on earth do you get that from? it's just ... meaningless. i have no words.

Comment: I am sorry for not checking exactly what you wrote and what I thought before commenting (which doesn't justify a downvote of someone else... they should think for themselfs instead of just voting because of a negativy comment appearing). Well, `p` could be a null-pointer constant, true (if it is of type `nullptr_t`, just like `nullptr` or a constant integer). So I shall change my question to: *Why must any value of basic type convert to bool?*

Comment: I definitely see the obvious need for pointers converting to bool (independent of C compatibility even), and also for integers (for C compatibility). But `nullptr` and `nullptr_t` is unique to C++, so I don't quite see the reason here (which is the reason why I formulated my first comment the way it is).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Originally basic type values had to convert to `bool` for C compatibility. C didn't originally have a `bool` type, but any numerical expression could be as a boolean (with the 0 == false convention). And now we're caught in the backward compatibility tangle. `nullptr` has to support idiomatic constructs such as `if(p)`, especially for the cases where old code's literal `0` or `NULL` is replaced with `nullptr`. E.g. it can result from a macro expansion.

Comment: I see. It would be a much better answer if you would have posted that as your text IMO.

Comment: Technically `nullptr_t` need not convert to `bool`.  It would be a bit strange, in that `if (nullptr)` would fail to compile while `if( ptr = nullptr )` would compile, but...  *however* if you wrote a `template` function where one of the arguments was pointer-like, being able to pass `nullptr` would be nice, and the `if` clauses would then occur.

Comment: I hope `if( ptr = nullptr )` gives a warning.

Comment: @VladimirF: E.g. `while( cin >> x )` is idiomatic code, and the safe way to do things. So to avoid sillywarnings on such constructs I would personally turn that warning off, if a compiler had it on by default. That said, I'm not sure what the subject is now. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  an assignment in an `if` that generates a dead branch (or a tautological `if`) is **often** a sign that `=` was used instead of `==`.

Answer (score 19):

> #### C++11 §4.12 *Boolean conversions*
>
> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, **null pointer value**, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`. A prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`; the resulting value is `false`.

It's true that `nullptr` is a keyword, but it's a null pointer literal, not the same role as `bool`. Think about the boolean literals, `true` and `false` are also keywords.

Comment: This answer does not go into the rationale of the rules, the "why"  requested by the OP. I.e. it's not even an answer. However, it's not incorrect.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I answered two things: <1> Why `nullptr` can be converted to a `bool`. <2> Why it can be used in the right hand side of `=` syntactically while apparently you can't put `bool` (which is also a keyword) there. Because `nullptr` is a literal, just like `42` or `true` (another keyword that is a literal). Perhaps we have different opinions of what the OP asks mainly, but I think my answer   answers at least some of the OP's question.

Comment: Uhm, as i see it <1>, the "why", is not answered. But <2>, about a confusion about types versus values, may be exactly what the OP was/is asking about. I didn't see that, sorry.

Comment: As the asker didn't specify his compiler, most probably his *"Why “bool c = nullptr ;” compiles"* was not intended as "Why does my compiler accept this? Satisfying customers? Just compliance?" (which your reply "because the standard requires that <here>" would indeed answer), but the question probably was "Why does the Standard require this somewhere?", which you don't answer at all. And I don't understand what "... but it's a null pointer literal, not the same role as bool" is intended to say. I would be glad if you clarified that part.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I didn't answer the question because I didn't think it was the main question at first, but then after @Cheers and hth. - Alf updates his answer, I don't think I can provide a better answer on this than his answer. I was emphasizing that `nullptr` is not the same kind of keyword than `bool`, its role is a literal of pointer type, just like `true` for `bool` type, but as I just saw OP's comment, it's not what he asked mainly. I would definitely update my answer to better suit OP's clarified question if I can think of a different view of @Alf's and your answer.

Answer (score 5):

In http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#654 , Jason Merril argues

> Anything we can do with an arbitrary pointer, we ought to be able to do with nullptr_t as well.

I think the following (slightly artificial) example supports that argument (although I am not totally sure if it was intended for this case)

```
template<typename T, typename P>
void safeProcess(T pointer, P &processor) {
  bool isNonNull(pointer);
  if(isNonNull) {
    processor.process(pointer);
  }
}
```

Which would allow passing `nullptr` along with other pointer types compatible with whatever `processor.process` accepts.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 corrects this by introducing a new keyword to serve as a distinguished null pointer constant: nullptr. It is of type nullptr_t, which is implicitly convertible and comparable to any pointer type or pointer-to-member type. It is not implicitly convertible or comparable to integral types, except for bool. While the original proposal specified that an rvalue of type nullptr should not be convertible to bool, the core language working group decided that such a conversion would be desirable, for consistency with regular pointer types. The proposed wording changes were unanimously voted into the Working Paper in June 2008.[2]

For backwards compatibility reasons, 0 remains a valid null pointer constant.

```
char *pc = nullptr;     // OK
int  *pi = nullptr;     // OK
bool   b = nullptr;     // OK. b is false.
int    i = nullptr;     // error
```